# USB keyboard dead at logon

Tags: usb, keyboard

When I reboot or startup my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS machine I'm not able to type my password in the login field. I'm trying to understand what the problem is. I have to plug the keyboard out and back in to be able to type the password.

At the bottom of `dmesg` I do see an error `couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint`. Could this be related? And how would I fix this? [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25570633/)

**dmesg:**

```
[   93.349435] hid-generic 0003:046D:C537.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[   93.352037] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8/3-8:1.1/0003:046D:C537.0005/input/input20
[   93.405519] hid-generic 0003:046D:C537.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input1
[   97.174469] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  107.304673] usb 3-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[  107.304675] usb 3-7: can't read configurations, error -110
[  107.416620] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[  107.546223] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b36
[  107.546225] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  107.546227] usb 3-7: Product: Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard 
[  107.546228] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Corsair
[  107.546229] usb 3-7: SerialNumber: 03029040AEB89C4755B969BDF5001944
[  107.547694] input: Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B36.0006/input/input21
[  107.600763] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B36.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
[  117.602050] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B36.0007: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[  117.602085] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B36.0007: timeout initializing reports
[  117.602997] input: Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B36.0007/input/input22
[  117.658421] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B36.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair Gaming K70 LUX Keyboard ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
[  117.658530] usbhid 3-7:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

Any help would be appreciated.